# Does a species appearing automatically unlock the special bitizen (?) in TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've noticed a few species in TDS that have appeared in my album, but it has not unlocked their special characters... I have noticed that once they appear the price to unlock them for Bux goes down to 1 Bux.

Does anyone know if these characters ever unlock on their own, or do you have to unlock them in the store for bux?  In other words, is it a special process by which these ? bitizens unlock in addition to the notification of the species unlocking?

As an example:  I have had both Mon Calamari, and Admiral Akbar appear in my TDS album, but I was not able to unlock the scene for the Mon Cala Aquarium until I paid the 1 Bux for the Mon Calamari special bitizen.

Here are photos as another example:  Look at the Toydarian in both photos, and just to muddy the water some, see that Snowtrooper?  I routinely get him as a ? bitizen.  Anyone have any idea WTF is going on here?

[image: Album Toydarian]

[image: Store Toydarian]

Comment: Are you talking about the Mon Calamari bitizen under Rebel Aliens? I have it unlocked and as far as I remember haven't paid any Bux to unlock characters. If it helps I am at 74 floors and have 2 droids, 6 men, 2 ladies, 2 rebels, 4 outer rim, 3 force, 3 cantina crew, and 1 henchmen still locked. Also, I think to unlock that scene it has to be the regular Mon Calamari Bitizen and not Ackbar.

Comment: I'm thinking that purchasing them may allow you to use them as an actual Bitizen you can employ. Otherwise they just show up as "?" Bitizens.

Comment: Also, when you say to look at both Toydarian Bitizens what should I be comparing? The color of their clothing?

Comment: Entirely possible.  But, honestly, I never got a Mon Calamari ? until I paid the bux.  I up-voted your "answer" because you deserve some rep for trying.  -- With regard to the Toydarians, I'm showing that it's an unlocked species, but still available for sale in the store.

Comment: I took a closer look at the list in my store. Most of the ones I have at 1 Bux to unlock I've seen as a "?" Bitizen before except for the Officer (both Black & Grey Uniform) and Mon Calamari. I will avoid purchasing those for now and update if I do happen to come across them.

Comment: I unlocked the Tusken Raider character the other day and when I went to check for it in the store it was gone. Perhaps there is/was a bug that was causing some characters to not be removed from the store after being unlocked?

Comment: Agreed.  Possibly a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I too have had the same experience with having the character, but not getting the occurrence of the scene.

I believe that the scene occurring is a random event based on if you have the characters.

If not, then it is one of the large number of bugs that are in the game. The developer has said they are working on them, but until then, this may be the cause of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the toydarian unlocked in my album and available in the store for 1 bux, yet seen many appear as ? While still available at the store.

When used from the store for 1 bux, he came and was delivered to a floor and checked back in the store and no more toydarian for sale, maybe the store is one use way to get a ? character?

Comment: Not always.  Seems to be a glitch in the game.  BTW - that Toydarian may be Watto, and not a mere Toydarian random.  That has been the case for many of the bitizens.  Admiral Akbar is the classic example.  I couldn't get a Mon Calamari to come out as a ? bitizen until I paid.  But, the place was lousy with Akbar.

Answer (score 0):

The initial, expensive, purchase of a character seems to be to throw them into the random lineup of people that go to your elevator.  When you do the "one buck thing", it is to give you a single shot of said toon, as the next character on your elevator.
Now with that,  in my experience, once you unlock the scene (for instance the Mon Cal aquarium, with normal mon cal) that species stops showing up, at all.  I unlocked said aquarium about a week ago, and haven't seen a normal mon cal since, and I was getting a ton of them prior to that. Same with jawas and droid store, though I never got jawas that didn't have a "?".

When a new species appears they seem to do so in waves, but then nothing for a long time.  Like I got the duros, devaronian, and chadra-fan all within an hour of each other.  But it's been days since then and they were the last new characters I received.  Prior to that, it was another wave of 3.  (like celebrity deaths).

I have to wonder what is the catalyst to unlocking species/characters (in free mode), if there is one.  I am still waiting on roughly 2/3 of the characters to unlock. I've got 57 levels but no Gam Guards, Weequays, and a ton of others.

Comment: Poke around on the posts marked Tiny Death Star.  You will see that the progression isn't tied to anything specific.  In fact, it seems to be time related.

Comment: I was actually doing that, and editing this post. That and I had the jawa going to the apts instead of the droid store.  When I finished, BAM there was your comment.  Good catch David.  

As a species fan, it's driving me up a wall not getting them to unlock faster. Like I want to use them in my stores, and they are not showing up....