# Does unlocking bitizens via the album make them available for play in the game?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've waited patiently for a few months for the Trandoshan species (my favorite!) and they haven't come, so I decided to use some bux, and unlock them and the Tusken Raider.

A week or so later, they still have yet to show up (even as elevator passengers)! So, I decided to run another test and unlock Zabrak, same problem.

I've read a theory that unlocks are the same for all players, and I today unlocked Sullustan, so my big question is; does unlocking in the album enable the species to show up and they still do not, or does it simply add their description and they will show up in the allotted amount of time?

Has anyone even had Trandoshan or Zabrak "randomly" unlock and become available as elevator passengers and/or residents? Or do we all just have to wait until they push the release button for us? My fear is that spending the bux in the album doesn't actually unlock them and locks them out from ever showing up,  I have even contemplated restarting my tower out of fear that I had glitched things for myself, but I decided to post here first :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  I was very close to flagging this question as a possible duplicate. But, I decided to hold off given that it is just *barely* different enough to qualify as a different question.  Please take the time to visit the tour under the help section.  It's very informative, helpful, and entertaining.

Comment: I will check it out thank you! Can you please link the question it was a duplicate to?

Comment: Look in my answer below.  It's kind of a cross between the two questions I suggested as having more information.  As I said, it was just different enough for me not to flag it . . .

Comment: BTW - That was meant as a constructive comment, not a criticism.  Your post was inherently good.  I cleaned it up a bit in edit for you.  People here will frequently flag a question if it smells familiar, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Also, for clarity, can I ask you to add if your are talking about them presenting as ? bitizens, or rather regular elevator passengers to the question.

Comment: I see, The difference would be I've spent the bux in the album with no signs of it working where all species unlocking naturally has worked and they show up, so is this intended or a glitch? Hoping someone has actually had a species show up after purchasing or else it's an actual complete waste of bux for species descriptions

Comment: I know it's constructive no worries :) I'm talking about them appearing as regular elevator riding employable bitizens

Comment: OK, edited to reflect that a bit clearer.  Again, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I used a bux to unlock a Bith via the store, but under Album, the spot where the Bith should occupy is still a "?". So I decided not to purchase anymore unlocks and wait for them to happen naturally in the course of the game. Also, not one Bith showed up on their own in my building after I bought the unlock. Perhaps Biths have high moral standards and are not easily bribed? ;)

On a related note, I once used a recruiting agent to fill up all 5 spots in my new residential floor. Among the 5 is a Weequay, which had yet to be unlocked in my game. So having new species as residents doesn't automatically unlock them for the game. I noticed the same thing happened again another time, with the same result. It was only when a Weequay took the elevator that the species is unlocked in my game.

So in conclusion, I think new species are only unlocked when they take the elevator, NOT when you buy them or when they appear as residents.

Comment: Are you sure the transaction went through when you bought the Bith?  I've never seen anyone encounter this. In fact, your install seems to be the most buggy ever. All of your posts contain very strange bugs.

Comment: Yes, it did. Because the Bith does not appear in my list of characters that I can buy anymore. I'm playing on a barely 3-week old iPhone 5s so it's unlikely to be a hardware issue? Perhaps you could try to buy a bitizen that you have yet to unlock, and see if that unlocks the species in your album?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked my phone again. I bought the Bith from the store for 1 bux, but it still remains unlockable in my album for 32 bux. So I mistakenly thought the two are the same when they are not. But I'm quite positive about the Weequay issue though.

Comment: OK, half the problem solved.  The Weequay probably proves your theory that they unlock only when the actually hit the elevator.  Someone else said that they've seen characters appear as customers before unlocking, too.  Must be related.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is valuable information, but a) I've unlocked a couple of *species* with bux, and none of them showed up yet neither on levels, nor in the elevator; b) all the *characters* (4-LOM and Hoth Luke) I've unlocked with bux started showing up as ? in the lift, just like everyone else.

Comment: This seems consistent with multiple people's observations. It is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've been unlocking all of the species without buying them.  Zabrak has definitely unlocked by itself, and I have several of them working for me.  I see Sullustan come as passengers, but I don't believe I have any working for me.

Trandoshan have not unlocked for me as yet.

There does seem to be some disconnect between the unlocking process and the characters appearing as ? bitizens.

From what I have seen, once you unlock a species it is immediately available.  Some species are, however, rarely appearing by their very nature.  There is, as far as I know, no published data on the appearance rates of any characters, but I definitely see Obi Wan very infrequently, for example.

You may want to look at the following two questions for more information:

[Which characters in Tiny Death Star can be unlocked without paying in Imperial Bux?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143685/62390)

[Does a species appearing automatically unlock the special bitizen (?) in TDS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146562/62390)

Comment: Likewise, all species that have unlocked themselves appear regularly and are residents, my problem is the ones I've unlocked have never shown in 5 days. I've seen the fluctuations like you said where some ? Characters appear more than others, but to unlock them and still have to wait for them to show up at a randomly chosen time seems like a giant waste of bux :( thank you for your great reply!!

Comment: Especially read my experience on the Does a species appearing automatically unlock the special bitizen in TDS?

Comment: I have read it and understand, my question is more so about the species unlocking and becoming employees and residents and not about them appearing as ? scene unlockers

Comment: Yeah, I think the game has a number of bugs like this . . . I think both issues are fairly similar.

Answer (score 1):

Both Tradoshan and Zabrak unlocked "by themselves" for me. Thing is, I've only had one Tradoshan ride the elevator so far - I agree some species are much rarer in appearances and I think that's independent of whether you paid to unlock them or played long enough to unlock them.

Answer (score 0):

After not seeing them appear days after paying bux for a species, when they frequently appear as employable and "?" characters when they unlock themselves naturally, I've decided that it must be a bug that they don't appear.Whether or not they appear eventually, I can't answer that as I've restarted my tower :( hopefully I can get the holiday stuff in two days! :p

Thank you all for the useful responses