# How do you unlock Yoda, R2-D2 or Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've built all levels and completed all missions in the game and I've still haven't seen Yoda, R2-D2 nor Darth Vader, despite having unlocked them in the Bitizens Album.  Why haven't they begun to appear in my elevator, yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already bought them in the album, check the store and see if they're for sale for 1 Bux.  If you pay for them there, they usually show up immediately in your elevator.

There is a related question on the site [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149043/does-unlocking-bitizens-via-the-album-make-them-available-for-play-in-the-game?rq=1) about whether unlocking the characters makes them available in the game.

Comment: I've unlocked all characters through the Bitizens album, yet I never get those characters on the elevator with a ? to unlock some scenes.

Comment: Check the store, and look at the bitizens for sale.  If you've unlocked anyone who isn't showing up, chances are they will be for sale for 1 Bux.  If you pay, they will appear in the elevator.  I've updated your question to reflect this.